# Sort multidimensional array and keep siblings

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I order the following array by `type` where `url` comes first, then `doc` then `page`?

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => '14',
        'position' => '0',
        'type' => 'related-url'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => '2367',
        'position' => '0',
        'type' => 'related-doc'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => '99',
        'position' => '0',
        'type' => 'related-page'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'id' => '180',
        'position' => '2',
        'type' => 'related-doc'
    ),
    5 => array(
        'id' => '10',
        'position' => '3',
        'type' => 'related-doc'
    )
);
```

The result would be

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => '14',
        'position' => '0',
        'type' => 'related-url'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => '2367',
        'position' => '0',
        'type' => 'related-doc'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'id' => '180',
        'position' => '2',
        'type' => 'related-doc'
    ),
    5 => array(
        'id' => '10',
        'position' => '3',
        'type' => 'related-doc'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => '99',
        'position' => '0',
        'type' => 'related-page'
    )
);
```

Maintaining key association isn't important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {

    $sortOrder = array(
        "related-url"   => 1,
        "related-doc"   => 2,
        "related-page"  => 3
    );

    return $sortOrder[$a['type']] - $sortOrder[$b['type']];
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is ugly, but it works)

```
$doc = array();
$url = array();
$page = array();

foreach($array as $v)
    switch($v['type']){
        case 'related-url': $url[] = $v;break;
        case 'related-doc': $doc[] = $v;break;
        case 'related-page': $page[] = $v;break;
    }

$array = array_merge($url, $doc, $page);
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go

```
function cmp($a, $b) {

    $v1 = $a['type'];
    $v2 = $b['type'];   
    $v1 = str_replace("related-", "", $v1);
    $v2 = str_replace("related-", "", $v2); 
    $firstChar = abs(ord(substr($v1,0,1)) - ord("u"));
    $firstChar2 = abs(ord(substr($v2,0,1)) - ord("u"));

    return $firstChar<=$firstChar2?-1:1; 

}

usort ( $array, "cmp" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use usort for this, heres a quick example.  I'm pretty sure this logic works but there is no doubt a better way to do it.

```
usort($your_array, function ($elem1, $elem2) {
  if($elem1['type'] == 'related-url')
    return true;

  elseif($elem2['type'] == 'related-url' )
    return false;

  elseif($elem1['type'] == 'related-doc')
    return true;

  else
    return false;
});
```

If element1 is a url it always returns true, if it isnt and element2 is a url it is always false.  If neither of those statements are true and element1 is a doc then return true as element2 is either doc or page.  Lastly if element1 is a page always return false as element2 is either a doc or page.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$urls = $docs = $pages = array();
foreach ($array as $sub) {
    switch($sub['type']) {
        case 'related-url':
            $urls[] = $sub;
        break;
        case 'related-doc':
            $docs[] = $sub;
        break;
        case 'related-page':
            $pages[] = $sub;
        break;
   }
}
$result = array_merge($urls, $docs, $pages);
echo '<pre>', var_dump($result), '</pre>';
```